# Using propensity scores from twang in coxph

Tags: survival, cox-model, propensity-scores

I've used the `twang` package to calculate propensity score weights in my observational data set. The `twang` vignette uses the `survey` package to apply the weighted PS in analyses, but does not provide an example for Cox proportional hazard estimation.

The `survey` package provides a function called `svycoxph()` which which seems to do the trick. However, when i use `coxph()` from the `survival` package an set the `weight=` argument to the extracted weighted PS from `twang`'s `ps()` object i get an indentical HR estimate, albeit a much more narrow 95%CI.

**Can I use the extracted propensity score weights from a ps object from the `twang` package as a vector in the `weight=` argument of the `survival` package's `coxph()`?**

Should i include an example?

**Update:** When i added a `cluster(patient ID)` term in the the `coxph` formula, both the HR and the 95% CI became identical to the `syvcoxph` output. So I guess that did the trick. But can i conclude that this is ok to use?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across your post because I used twang to calculate inverse probability weights and wanted to use a coxph model afterwards. I had used svyglm before, but wasn't aware of svycoxph. So thanks for this hint.

I tried what you did and got almost identical results with coxph and cluster(patient ID) as with svycoxph.

In the description of svycoxph, they say:

> The main difference between ‘svycoxph’ function and the ‘robust=TRUE’ option to ‘coxph’ in the survival package is that this function accounts for the reduction in variance from stratified sampling and the increase in variance from having only a small number of clusters.

In the description of coxph, they give the following explanation:

> The term ‘+ cluster(id)’ where each value of ‘id’ is unique is equivalent to specifying the ‘robust=T’ argument, and produces an approximate jackknife estimate of the variance.

From these two explanations I conclude that coxph using cluster(id) is fine for large numbers of clusters (what you probably had). If you have a small number of clusters and want to account for this, svycoxph will be safer. In my case, with 67 clusters, it made a small difference so I will use svycoxph.